# Form mvc3 razor partialview post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a partialView _BasicInfoPartView associate to BasicInfoModel.
This partialview contains some input and dropdownlist as:

```
public class BasicInfoModel 
{       public string Name { get; set; }
        public string selectedRubric { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Rubrics { get; set; }
}
```

Partial _BasicInfoPartView.cshtml

```
@model ProjectZeroWebSite.Models.PleGroupModel
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.selectedRubric, @Model.Rubrics })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name )
```

This partialview can be call in a FORM in any page. Just need to add BasicInfoModel in the page model.

```
public class RandomPageModel
{
        public basicInfoModel { get; set; }
        public string info2{ get; set; }
        ...
        public RandomPageModel()
        { this.basicInfoModel = new basicInfoModel ();}
}
```

RandomPage.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Partial("_BasicInfoPartView ", @Model.BasicInfoModel)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.info2)
    ...
    <input type="submit"  />
}
```

Now the problem:
I can populate the page without problem.
But when I try to retrieve the information in the controller from the model:
RandomPageModel.info2 OK!
RandomPageModel.BasicInfoModel is empty...

I think i miss understand the databinding concept :s
I try this because i did not want overload my pages by small JS functions and dont like the idea t copy past my forms (code maintenance).

Thanks by advance.

Cantinos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an editor template instead of a partial view in this case.

So you define an editorTemplate (strongly typed)

```
@model BasicInfoModel

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.selectedRubric, @Model.Rubrics })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name )
```

Name this editor template the same as the model and put it in a folder called EditorTemplates in the Shared view folder

> ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/BasicInfoModel.cshtml

And then swap out this line

```
@Html.Partial("_BasicInfoPartView ", @Model.BasicInfoModel)
```

for this one

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BasicInfoModel)
```

Comment: You may rid of "_" in the name of the editor template and use @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BasicInfoModel)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works but I needed to put @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BasicInfoModel, **"BasicInfoPartView"**) for he finds the view

Comment: Yes, if the name of the template differs from that of the model, you have to supply that name as the second argument.  Glad you got it working!